# How to find all questions that were duplicates of another question?

Tags: support, questions, search, duplicate-questions, linked-questions

I am interested to see a list of all questions that were closed because being a dup of another question.

I strongly want to research a particular question and reading all the answers inside the dups will help me a lot.

Is there such feature? if not, this is a feature request

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can search for them (sort of) with the syntax `url:"http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/*" closed:1`. That will show you all closed questions that include the link to the question URL included, change the URL as needed for the question you need.

The Linked sidebar animuson references is a good start, but also includes all posts that either link to that question or are linked to from within that question. The closed:1 search operator limits you to closed posts, which are more likely the duplicates you're looking for.

Comment: I like this approach more

Comment: Another reason to not use the shortened URLs for linking on these sites! ;-) (Of course, one could [search for](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2F*%2F7237%2F*%22+closed%3A1) `url:"http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*/7237/*" closed:1` instead.)

Comment: @Arjan thanks, that must include far more results since the minified links when sharing links are `/q/`. However, I am not sure if using `closed:1` is enough to filter out answers, maybe we should use `/q*/` or `is:question`

Answer (score 3):

When a question gets closed as a duplicate of another, it gets "linked" on the right side of the question that it duplicates. Basically it looks for other posts which have a URL to that question contained within them (the "Possible Duplicate" box for closed questions). For example, take a look at [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) here on meta. You can click on "see more linked questions..." to get a search result of all posts linking to the question.

Comment: This isn't always an efficient way to find duplicates, since the "linked" questions are not guaranteed to be duplicates. I hope Stack Overflow will eventually implement [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211366/group-duplicate-questions-for-convenience), since it will make it much easier to find duplicate questions.